# At airports in Cambodia, should I be prepared for a visa scam?

Tags: visas, cambodia, scams

When entering Cambodia by land, many people write that the Cambodian officials will try to scam you for more money than the visa costs (US $20):

> We have already read about a bunch of scams the Cambodian officials will try to pull, one of which simply involved asking you for an extra 100 baht ($3.50 CAD). You could pay it just to make life easier, but we didn’t want to on principle. What’s funny is that we didn’t expect how blatantly obvious it would be. Once we handed over our completed forms, $20 USD and a photo, they pointed to a clipboard on the counter, with “20 US + 100 baht” written on a white piece of paper, in bubble lettering…

[(link)](http://artydubs.com/2013/04/18/direct-bus-from-bangkok-thailand-to-siem-reap-cambodia/)

Should I expect the same treatment when flying into Cambodia?

Answer (score 6):

The 100 Baht you are being charged is not always a scam. In MOST cases it is actually a genuine processing fee that many other countries also charge but include in the total price. If you are flying into Cambodia it is very easy to avoid any kind of scam as long as you fly into Phnom Penh International Airport or into Siem Reap International Airport. You can apply for a visa here http://evisa.mfaic.gov.kh and pay the $25 total cost by credit card.

If you decide to fly into any other airport in Cambodia you may find yourself in big trouble as they don't have the facilities to expend visas. Of course, you will always find someone willing to "help" you and they will but it will cost you. Unfortunately it will be your only option.

It is also true that, when crossing into Cambodia by land, even those border stations that can and should offer a pretty easy process for your visa application, are known for trying to get some extra cash on the side. In the end it can be construed as a scam but, if you already know Cambodia, you'll also understand that most people have to find a way to make a living in whatever way they can. It isn't more of a reap-off than the overprized food and drinks you'll find in the horribly westernized Siem Reap's Pub Street.

Answer (score 2):

I did not encounter any scam of sort when entering Cambodia over land. There was a small processing fee for the visa payable at the border.

Vietnam on the other hand, I had to pay an additional amount for the stamp in my passport that would authorize me to leave the country. Despite the small amount I felt this was a bit of a scam.